# Generating a 20x20 matrix in Python using a similar method to if else loops

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.6

I need to generate a 20x20 matrix but only really have previous knowledge of coding from c++:

```
Do i=-20,20
 Do j=-20,20
if i=j, then
 A(i,j)=1-(i/sqrt(3))
else
 A(i,j)=e^(i*phi*abs(i-j))
```

Obviously sloppy and not properly written but you get the idea I hope!

How would I input this in python?

The only method I have found so far is using numpy as np.array however you can imagine i'm not using python to input ~ 400 terms in an array.

Comment: What is phi ? Is that PI? or you have a value for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a grid

```
i, j = np.ogrid[-20:20:2, -20:20:2]
```

and compute your term on the entire grid in one go

```
A = np.exp(i*phi*np.abs(i-j))
```

The diagonal I would fix afterwards

```
i, j = np.diag_indices_from(A)
A[i, j] = 1-i/np.sqrt(3)
```

Comment: I knew neither `ogird` nor `diag_indices_from` awesome. This is so neat. Maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: @Bharath numpy has quite a few of those little conveniences. I think it's near impossible to know them all.

Comment: I run into trouble when python tries to compute the i in the exponent or diagonal. The i in this case is the imaginary number i, as opposed to the index i used for the grid. 

Phi is just some constant that needs to be present. How would I define phi as a variable?

How would I go about getting python to express the grid in terms of the general terms instead of numerically trying to solve it? i.e the first row would be "1-i/sqrt(3)","e^(i*phi)",e^(i*2*phi*)... where i have just solved the i-j part. @PaulPanzer (thank you so much for your help already too!)

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% follow, but whereever you mean the imaginary unit just put `1j` insteaad of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of vectorization to get rid of for loop i.e

A for loop approach :

```
arr2 = np.array([np.arange(0,20)]*20,dtype=float)

for i in range(arr2.shape[0]):
     for j in range(arr2.shape[1]):
        if i-j:
            arr2[i,j] =1-(i/np.sqrt(3))
        else:
            arr2[i,j] = np.e**(i*np.pi*abs(i-j))
```

Numpy vectorization approach

```
arr = np.array([np.arange(0,20)]*20,dtype=float).T

mask = np.diag(np.diag(arr)).astype(bool)
new_arr = np.where(mask,np.e**(arr*np.pi*np.abs(arr - arr.T)),1-(arr/np.sqrt(3)))

(arr2 == new_arr).all()
# True
```

Comment: Here I used np.pi, if your `phi` is some constant replace `np.pi` with `phi`